# Шифрование сообщений wcf-сервис

Tags: безопасность, wcf

Совсем недавно работаю с wcf. Есть wcf-сервис, который размещается в службах Windows. На данный момент используется для биндинг **basicHttpBinding** с режимом безопасности **BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly** и типом учетных данных **HttpClientCredentialType.Basic**. В сервисе реализован **UserNamePasswordValidator** для проверки вводимого на клиенте логина и пароля. Сам сервис и его клиенты находятся в Internet. Понимаю, что такой вариант не есть хорошо, т.к. все данные передаются в открытом виде, их можно подменить и бла-бла-бла. Нужно обеспечить хотя бы шифрование данных, но при изучении этого вопроса всюду натыкаюсь, что если сервис и клиенты не в локальной сети, то нужно использовать сертификаты. А их соответственно нужно покупать в центре сертификации, что не хотелось бы делать. Можно, но тоже не желательно, использовать утилиты для самостоятельной генерации сертификатов. Но такие сертификаты, вроде как, придется загружать на клиентский компьютер, что для пользователя очень сложно. Подскажите, есть более простой способ для моего случая? Без сертификатов, или это утопия?

Answer (score 1):

От чего планируете защищаться? Если от перехвата трафика -- то вам действительно нужно смотреть в сторону https, а это значит -- без сертификатов **никак** не обойтись.

Вот что нужно сказать. Это у вас коммерческий проект или некоммерческий? Для организации лучше приобрести самый простенький SSL-сертификат, это не так уж и дорого. Либо он может уже быть, если покупали "для сайта", нужно лишь сконвертировать.

Если же проект личный, некоммерческий -- то почему бы вам не рассмотреть вариант с получением бесплатных сертификатов?

Раньше у китайцев (WoSign) можно было получить на три года wildcard бесплатно (sic!!!), я сейчас для мелких личных проектов перешёл на использование LetsEncrypt. Для unix-проектов они вообще бесподобно хороши, под windows не очень удобны тем, что нет официального клиента.

Про самоподписанные сертификаты вы всё правильно пишете - да, их нужно устанаваливать на клиентский компьютер, что не всегда удобно.

Comment: Перехват не очень критичен, главное чтобы данные не были открытыми, шифровались. Проект коммерческий. Сервис будет развертываться для нескольких организаций. Тогда и сертификат нужно для каждой организации отдельный, я так понимаю? Кроме того не в каждой организации встречаются адекватные админы, готовые выполнять лишние действия. Поэтому хотелось бы максимально простой вариант.

Comment: @Atsk Уточните, что значит "развёртываться для нескольких организаций"? Если у вас дома стоит один сервер, а несколько организаций -- это несколько организаций-клиентов, у каждой по 100 компьютеров, то нет, вам нужен лишь один сертификат на свой сервер. Если вам нужно развернуть несколько серверов с идентичным кодом у разных организаций  (и к серверу организации могут подключаться только сто компьютеров её сотрудников из интернет) -- то вам нужно на каждую организацию один сертификат.

Comment: В моем случае используется второй вариант описанный вами: "нужно развернуть несколько серверов с идентичным кодом у разных организаций (и к серверу организации могут подключаться только сто компьютеров её сотрудников из интернет)"

Comment: @Atsk Тогда каждая организация должна будет взять себе один сертификат, на выбранное себе доменное имя. Не знаю, почему вы так беспокойтесь по этому поводу, если не брать совсем мелкие организации, в которых нет собственного админа, но вообще-то операция установки сертификата не такая и сложная по нынешним меркам. Чай, не эксчейндж разворачивать. А если вы оставите инструкцию - так вообще заурядная. Это ж как сайт, точно такой же сертификат, а сайты сейчас у каждой конторы есть.

Comment: @A K, А если все-таки акцентироваться на том, что перехват трафика не так уж страшен, нужно только шифровать  данные, то все равно кроме сертификатов никаких вариантов?

Comment: @Atsk "Нужно только шифровать данные" -- сформулируйте угрозу безопасности более чётко. От кого шифровать, зачем? Когда объясните сценарий -- тогда можно будет сказать, какие есть варианты.

Comment: @A K клиенты боятся, что данные передаются в открытом виде, в случае перехвата, кто-то может извлечь из них то-то полезное. На самом деле вероятность, что кто-то будет этим заниматься очень мала.

Comment: @Atsk Ну то есть всё же именно перехват трафика и только он. Рекомендую остановиться на https - этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: @A K сейчас используется протокол http, как прикрутить https я не понимаю. Можете в двух словах пояснить как это организовать? Напомню, что сервис хостится в службе Windows.